# Автоматически генерировать поле в select запросе

Tags: sql, clickhouse

У меня есть запрос

```
select B.cohort_month,
       S.num_users as total_users,
       B.month_number,
       B.num_users * 100 / S.num_users as percentage
from (select C.cohort_month,
             A.month_number,
             count(1) as num_users
      from (select A.device_id,
                   dateDiff('month', cm.cohort_month, toDate(date_trunc('month', event_date))) as month_number
            from logs.track A
                     left join (SELECT device_id,
                                       date_trunc('month', min(event_date)) cohort_month
                                FROM logs.track
                                WHERE app_name in ('com.yard', 'com.yard')
                                GROUP BY device_id) cm
                               ON A.device_id = cm.device_id
            where app_name in ('com.citylan.yard', 'com.yard')
            group by A.device_id, month_number) A
               left join (SELECT device_id,
                                 date_trunc('month', min(event_date)) cohort_month
                          FROM logs.track
                          WHERE app_name in ('com.yard', 'com.yard')
                          GROUP BY device_id) C ON A.device_id = C.device_id
      group by C.cohort_month, A.month_number) B
         left join (select cohort_month, count(1) as num_users
                    from (SELECT device_id,
                                 date_trunc('month', min(event_date)) cohort_month
                          FROM logs.track
                          WHERE app_name in ('com.yard', 'com.yard')
                          GROUP BY device_id)
                    group by cohort_month
                    order by cohort_month) S ON B.cohort_month = S.cohort_month
where B.cohort_month IS NOT NULL
order by B.cohort_month, B.month_number;
```

Он формирует таблицу следующего вида
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно, что бы была таблица такого вида
[image: | Cohort_month | total_user | month_0 | month_1 | month_2 | | --------- | -------------- |-------------- |-------------- |-------------- | | 2021-08-01 | 481 |100% |83.57 % |65 % | | 2021-09-01 | 1323 |100% |76.34 % |67.57 % |]

и так до текущего месяца, дело в том что, количество месяцев не фиксированно (month_0, month_1, month_2 и т.д.) и каждый месяц будте +1 месяц, можно ли как то сделать что бы поле формировалось автоматически?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так что-бы совсем динамический получилось колонка из значения ресурсами SQL скорее всего никак, Но можно через CASE прогнать, и с интересующими тебя колонками.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns

Хотя отдельный гвоздь в гроб, хз поддерживает ли ClickHouse case'инг

Comment: ps: Единственная субд которая такое может вытворять из коробки, это MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлять колонки динамически, не зная заранее их количество, нельзя (есть функция `untuple`, но количество элементов в `tuple` фиксированно). Но можно использовать массив, в котором хранить вычисления от заданного момента времени по текущий. Напримр, так можно сгенерировать массив:

```sql
WITH toDate('2021-02-01') AS begin_date
SELECT arrayMap(x -> (begin_date + toIntervalMonth(x)), range(toUInt32(dateDiff('month', begin_date, toStartOfMonth(today())) + 1)))
```

```
┌─arrayMap(lambda(tuple(x), plus(begin_date, toIntervalMonth(x))), range(toUInt32(plus(dateDiff('month', begin_date, toStartOfMonth(today())), 1))))─┐
│ ['2021-02-01','2021-03-01','2021-04-01','2021-05-01','2021-06-01','2021-07-01','2021-08-01','2021-09-01','2021-10-01','2021-11-01','2021-12-01']   │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Если динамичность ну нужна, тогда можно просто добавть колонки, перечислив варианты.

Оператор [CASE](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/operators/#operator_case) и [miltiIf](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional-functions/#multiif) поддерживается